# What factors does the opensea NFT origination gas cost depend on?

Tags: nft, gas-estimate, opensea

I am trying to understand what `opensea NFT origination gas fees` depend on. My main question is if the fees depend on the size of NFT (video vs plain image), but I have put together a list of all factors I am aware of so far, could you correct it if it contains mistakes/omissions? The factors I have got so far are as below:

1. Creator's decision to use [lazy minting](https://opensea.io/learn/nft-gas-fees#toc-2) (then the first buyer pays the gas origination cost) or to do the regular minting (then the creator pays the costs)
2. Day/time of the day of minting (if not lazy minting) and day/time of the day of buying (if lazy minting) - [Mondays tend to be the most expensive, weekends tend to be the cheapest](https://ethereumprice.org/gas/)
3. Complexity (size in MB?) of NFT - I presume it could affect the gas cost. [Opensea allows files up to 100MB](https://support.opensea.io/hc/en-us/articles/360061943574-What-file-formats-can-I-use-to-make-NFTs-Is-there-a-maximum-size-), but most images are much smaller. There is [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136825/do-gas-prices-for-nfts-depend-on-file-size) about the file size, and I am only interested in opensea, so I would like to double-check.
4. Contract type: [opensea allows ERC-721 and ERC-1155](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/getting-started), and it seems that [ERC-1155 is both more flexible and more cost-efficient](https://www.chetu.com/blogs/blockchain/erc-721-vs-erc-1155.php#:%7E:text=Batch%20Transfers%3A%20ERC%2D1155%20can,transactions%20and%20higher%20gas%20fees.).

[The gas cost of the first NFT created after the merge earlier this year is $60K, and it's just a small, very plain image](https://nftnewspro.com/gas-fee-for-first-minted-nft-following-merge-is-60000/) - why is it so expensive? Was it because everyone was trying to create the first-after-merge NFT, and it caused the prices to skyrocket? Or is there anything to learn from this case that can help to reduce the gas fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one of the factors the opensea NFT origination gas fee depends on is the file size of the NFT, as higher images cost more, but the time this will affect gas prices is when they are minted and only if the metadata of the image is stored on-chain. The gas cost of the first NFT created after the merge earlier this year is so expensive ($60K) because although it's just a small, very plain image, the Merge only changed the overall consensus mechanism. The event did not expand the network capacity, so there will be no significant reduction in gas fees.

See:

https://nftclub.com/what-file-size-should-an-nft-be/

https://www.investing.com/news/cryptocurrency-news/first-minted-nft-after-merge-costs-60000-in-gas-fee-2893023

You can save gas fees when minting NFT by using Layer-2 sidechains, finding an NFT tool that uses lazy minting, using different blockchain networks, and customizing fees for transactions.

See: https://www.nftically.com/blog/five-ways-to-save-gas-fees-when-minting-nfts/